# iOS Multiple Delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, delegates, delegation

I need a couple of my `view controllers` to know when Persons `dictionary` is getting changed.
I have created a protocol, but as I understand, the delegate property can have only one `delegate`, and not an array of `delegates`.
I know I can implement this using the `NSNotification`, but is there any way to do it with `delegation`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegates are meant to be for One to One.
For multiple listeners `NSNotification` is the way to go, as you know.